# Installing Windows 8 alongside Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows

I had Windows 8 installed on my laptop (64-bit) and when I installed ubuntu on it I made a huge mistake and removed windows 8 and every file with it. What done is done.. I've been running ubuntu 13.04 for a month now and I would like to install windows 8 again alongside ubuntu.

I want it to be a dual boot, so when I start my laptop I can choose between the two. Installing windows 8 will be legit from a website from my university, I can just download it for free.

How to do this??
 (- Do I need to use a harddrive/cd to put Windows on?)

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1.Make free space for Windows 8 
2.format the free space with an NTFS filesystem using gparted 
3.use [WINUSB](http://www.unixmen.com/winusb-create-bootable-windows-usb-linux/) tool to create windows 8 bootable usb(skip this if you have windows 8 DVD)
4.Windows 8 Installation will destroy the grub2 bootloader so you will not be able to boot into Ubuntu to solve that problem you have to [**reinstall grub using ubuntu live usb/dvd**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lod8sRb_6I)